# how to get specific rows from csv file?

Tags: c, arrays, string, csv, struct

I've written a code, wherein i'm trying to get all the rows which start from **"A"**. I have A, A12 etc in my csv file and i want to read all those rows. But i got the following error. Not sure where i went wrong. Kindly help.

**CSV file**

```
M,2,lion
A,1,tiger
B,2,cat
A1,7,dog
C,3,man
A2,9,mouse
A23,9,pouch
```

**myfile.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMLETTERS 100

typedef struct {
    char letter[100];
    int number;
    char ani[100];
} record_t;

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    record_t records[NUMLETTERS];
    size_t count = 0;

    fp = fopen("letters.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, " %s,%d,%s", records[count].letter, &records[count].number, records[count].ani) == 3) {
        count++;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(records[i].letter== "A"){
        printf("%s,%d,%s\n", records[i].letter, records[i].number,records[i].number);
    }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
myfile.c:29:16: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%s,%d,%s\n", records[i].letter, records[i].number,records[i].number);
```

Comment: Note that `records[i].letter== "A"` will compare two *pointers* and that those pointers will never be equal.

Comment: As for the *warning* it tells you exactly what's wrong. If you can't see it yourself in the `printf` line (re-read it a couple of times) then show it to a friend, or get a good nights sleep and come back to it tomorrow.

Comment: Looks like [how to get specific rows from csv file with exact data using c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034462/how-to-get-specific-rows-from-csv-file-with-exact-data-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

Since you search fields that start with `A`, you only need to compare the first letter of `letter`, so your line 28 becomes:

```
if(records[i].letter[0] == 'A'){
```

And your compiler told you that you try to display an integer as a string, it's because you have a typo in line 29: `number` instead of `ani`, the line should be:

```
printf("%s,%d,%s\n", records[i].letter, records[i].number,records[i].ani);
```

> Sorry i got my output but some extra column added in my output as "0" A,1,tiger,0, A1,7,dog,0, A2,9,mouse,0, A23,9,pouch,0, – Abhik 2 hours ago

It comes from your `scanf` call: in `scanf`, `%s` will read until in find a space (space or tab or line feed). You have to tell to scanf to stop too read `letter` after the first comma found. To do this, replace `%s` with `%99[^,]`. More explanations here: [Scanf guide](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

So your reading loop should looks like:

```
while (fscanf(fp, " %99[^,],%d,%s", records[count].letter, &records[count].number, records[count].ani) == 3) {
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i got my output but some extra column added in my output as  "0"                      A,1,tiger,0,
A1,7,dog,0,
A2,9,mouse,0,
A23,9,pouch,0,