# how to get specific rows from csv file with exact data using c?

Tags: c, csv, struct

This is my csv file, i want to get only those row which start with character "A" so i got my output but with some addition column as '0' please help me to find were i went wrong?

And one more thing i want to remove specific column like bread,anName,ot

```
Name,id,bread,anName,Ot,number
A,1,animal,tiger,op,8.1
M,2,animal,toper,ip,9.1
A1,7,animal,dog,cp,Na11
A2,9,animal,mouse,ap,0
A23,9,animal,pouch,gp,Na11
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMLETTERS 100

typedef struct {
    char Name[100];
    int id;
    char number[100];
} record_t;

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    record_t records[NUMLETTERS];
    int count = 0, i;

    fp = fopen("letter.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s,%d,%s", records[count].name, &records[count].id, records[count].number) == 1) 
        count++;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(records[i].Name[0] == 'A'){
            printf("%s,%d,%s\n", records[i].Name, records[i].id, records[i].number);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

i want output as:

```
A,1,8.1
A1,7,Na11
A2,9,0
A23,9,Na11
```

Comment: grep -r "A" > Output.txt. If only the file exists in a linux env

Comment: And i want to skip the column of numbers also, i want only  A with last name..

Comment: Actually i have to do it with C programming only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get specific rows from csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006396/how-to-get-specific-rows-from-csv-file)

Comment: This looks like the same question you posted two days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006396/how-to-get-specific-rows-from-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

You have *two* problems:

1. The `%s` format specifier tells [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read a *space-delimited* string. Since the the records aren't space-delimited the first `%s` will read the whole line.
2. The `fscanf` function [returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) the number of successfully parsed elements it handled. Since you attempt to read three values you should compare with `3` instead of `1`.

---

Now for *one* way how to solve the first problem: Use the `%[` format specifier. It can handle simple patterns and, most importantly, *negative* patterns (read while input does not match).

So you could tell `fscanf` to read a string until it finds a comma by using `%[^,]`:

```
fscanf(fp, " %[^,],%d,%s", records[count].Refdes, &records[count].pin, records[count].NetName)
```

The use of the `%[` specifier is only needed for the first string, as the second will be space-delimited (the newline).

Also note that there's a space before the `%[` format, to read and ignore leading white-space, like for example the newline from the previous line.

Comment: ok, but how to remove the column which start with 1,2 pins, how to remove that.

Comment: @Abhik What do you mean by "remove"? What is the *expected* output? Please edit your question to include it. Or better yet, since it's a different problem then ask a separate question for it. But before you do that, please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: sorry i am new to this actually, i want to remove second column of my csv file

Comment: @Abhik Remove it from the *file* or just not print it?

Comment: i have more then 5,6 column and 3000 data in csv file, so i have to get specific row and  column

Answer (score 0):

> i want to get only those row which start with character "A"
>
> i want to remove the number which coming between A and tiger,

If I understand you correctly and you only want to store rows beginning with `'A'`, then I would adjust your approach to read each line with `fgets()` and then check whether the first character in the buffer is `'A'`, if so, `continue;` and get the next line. The for those lines that do start with `'A'`, simply use `sscanf` to parse the data into your array of struct `records`.

For your second part of removing the number between `'A'` and `"tiger"`, there is a difference between what you *store* and what you *output* (this comes into play in storing only records beginning with `'A'` as well), but for those structs stored where the line starts with `'A'`, you can simply not-output the `pin` struct member to get the output you want.

The approach to reading a line at a time will simply require that you declare an additional character array (buffer), called `buf` below, to read each line into with `fgets()`, e.g.

```
    char buf[3 * NUMLETTERS] = "";
    ...
    /* read each line into buf until a max of NUMLETTERS struct filled */
    while (count < NUMLETTERS && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {   
        record_t tmp = { .Refdes = "" };    /* temporary struct to read into */
        if (*buf != 'A')                    /* if doesn't start with A get next */
            continue;
        /* separate lines beginning with 'A' into struct members */
        if (sscanf (buf, " %99[^,],%d,%99[^\n]",
                    tmp.Refdes, &tmp.pin, tmp.NetName) == 3)
            records[count++] = tmp;         /* assign tmp, increment count */
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "%d A record - invalid format.\n", count + 1);
    }
```

A short example putting that to use and (since we are not sure what `"remove"` is intended to be), we have included a pre-processor conditional that will only output the `.Refdes` and `.NetName` members by default, but if you either `#define WITHPIN` or include the define in your compile string (e.g. `-DWITHPIN`) it will output the `.pin` member as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMLETTERS 100

typedef struct {
    char Refdes[NUMLETTERS];
    int pin;
    char NetName[NUMLETTERS];
} record_t;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    record_t records[NUMLETTERS];
    char buf[3 * NUMLETTERS] = "";
    int count = 0, i;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line into buf until a max of NUMLETTERS struct filled */
    while (count < NUMLETTERS && fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {   
        record_t tmp = { .Refdes = "" };    /* temporary struct to read into */
        if (*buf != 'A')                    /* if doesn't start with A get next */
            continue;
        /* separate lines beginning with 'A' into struct members */
        if (sscanf (buf, " %99[^,],%d,%99[^\n]",
                    tmp.Refdes, &tmp.pin, tmp.NetName) == 3)
            records[count++] = tmp;         /* assign tmp, increment count */
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "%d A record - invalid format.\n", count + 1);
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
#ifdef WITHPIN
        printf ("%-8s %2d     %s\n",
                records[i].Refdes, records[i].pin, records[i].NetName);
#else
        printf ("%-8s     %s\n", records[i].Refdes, records[i].NetName);
#endif
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getaonly dat/getasonly.txt
A            tiger
A1           dog
A2           mouse
A23          pouch
```

If you define `-DWITHPIN` in your compile string, then you will get all three outputs:

```
$ ./bin/getaonly dat/getasonly.txt
A         1     tiger
A1        7     dog
A2        9     mouse
A23       9     pouch
```

(**note:** with the data stored in your array, you can adjust the output format to anything you need)

Since there is some uncertainty whether you want to store all and output only records beginning with `'A'` or only want to store records beginning with `'A'` -- let me know if I need to make changes and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question i edit my question. please help me to find the solution

Comment: Thank you so much i got my output.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Let me know if you have any more questions.